# Capture low quality video/audio/pictures with Cordova

Tags: cordova

I'm using the [`cordova-plugin-media-capture`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture) because I can capture video, audio and photos with it, all needed for the app I'm developing.

Sadly I can't find any options to set the quality of this elements. Should I use `cordova-plugin-camera` for photos and `cordova-plugin-media` for audio instead?

Any other option? What about video?

Comment: check this out...https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture#example--android-w-quality-

Comment: @Banik sorry, is not what im looking for

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?